# Template instantiations and pimpl idiom with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, unique-ptr, pimpl-idiom

I read this answer by Howard Hinnant ([Is std::unique_ptr<T> required to know the full definition of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t)) and then this answer ([How is a template instantiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598635/how-is-a-template-instantiated)) and I was just thinking.  If you have a class like so

```
class Something {
    Something(); 
    ~Something();
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl;
};
```

The `unique_ptr` will be instantiated at that point when the class is compiled (as I could make out from the other answer above).  Then why is it okay to not have the class `Impl` defined later on?  Won't the instantiation require the destructor of `Impl` to be present?

**Note** The following is in an effort to clarify what I am asking above.

The way I am thinking about it, when the compiler goes over the definition of the class `Something`.  It will see the declaration of the nested class `Impl` and then it will see the declaration of the `unique_ptr<Impl>`, and at that point.  It will instantiate the template `unique_ptr` with `Impl`.  And that instantiated code will contain a call to the destructor of `Impl`.  Since at this point we have code that includes a call to the destructor of an incomplete class, how is the code above safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The accepted answer to the first question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089065/434551) contains a table of use cases where the complete definition of `Impl` is required.

In your case, the compiler implicitly generates the following member functions:

- Copy constructor
- Move constructor
- Copy assignment operator
- Move assignment operator.

All of them require the complete definition of `Impl`.

If you explicitly declare those functions and define them where the complete definition of `Impl` is available, you'll be OK.

**Update**

> It will see the declaration of the nested class `Impl` and then it will see the declaration of the `unique_ptr<Impl>`, and at that point. It will instantiate the template `unique_ptr` with `Impl`.

That is correct only to an extent. Not all member functions of `unique_ptr` will be instantiated at that time.

> And that instantiated code will contain a call to the destructor of `Impl`.

Not correct. The compiler will generate the code (or instantiate) the destructor of `std::unique_ptr<Impl>` only when it is needed. That place is the destructor of `Something`.

Destructor of `Something` will need destructor of `std::unique_ptr<Impl>`.
Destructor of `std::unique_ptr<Impl>` needs the complete definition of `Impl`.

In other words, the complete definition of `Impl` must be visible to the destructor of `Something`.

**PS**

More on template instantiation can be found at [Template instantiation details of GCC and MS compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182359/template-instantiation-details-of-gcc-and-ms-compilers).

Comment: Member functions for which class?  Also I saw the accepted answer to the first question but still did not understand,  the complete `unique_ptr` class will be instantiated with the given type at that point in code (the declaration of the pointer to impl) and with that instantiation will be the code that calls the destructor of `Impl` , but that is not yet visible.  Then how does the code compile?

Comment: @Curious, in the linked answer, `P` is either `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`. In your case, the implicitly generated copy constructor will invoke the copy constructor of `unique_ptr<Impl>`. Extend that logic to the other compiler generated member functions of your class.

Comment: I don't think I am conveying my thoughts properly,  I'll try and clarify in the question

Comment: Posted the clarification!

Comment: @Curious, I added an Update that responds to your concerns.

Comment: Thanks!  Could you link me to something that explains how template instantiation works?  I feel like I am missing some things there.  Like I don't really know which functions are instantiated when.

Comment: @Curious, I added a link to a relevant question on SO.

Comment: Great thanks!  One last thing, from the title of the question that is just explaining the template instantiation for GCC and Microsoft compilers.  Does that mean that different compilers have different side effects when it comes to template instantiation?  And if so does that also imply that the same code might work on one compiler and not another when it comes to things like mentioned in my question?

Comment: @Curious, I haven't looked up the standard but from the accepted answer to that question: *Whether a compiler actually implements two-phase lookup is not dictated by the standard. To be conformant, however, it should work as if it did*.

Answer (score 0):

If you write try to compile the above code and create an object of Something, it will give an error message :

```
Semantic issue:
memory:2523:27: Invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 
'Something::Impl'
```

In short the code is uncompilable and there is no point of taking about safety in this case.